# Delete a user from a room Django

Tags: django

In my app, I have created rooms where participants(users) can message.

In **models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class Topic(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self) :
        return self.name

class Room(models.Model):
    host = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='participants', blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-updated', '-created']
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.body[0:50]
```

Now, in the participants section, I have added a user whenever the user sends a message sends a message for the first time in that room.

In **views.py**

```
def room(request, pk):
    room = Room.objects.get(id=pk)
    room_messages = room.message_set.all().order_by('-created')
    participants = room.participants.all()
    print(participants.all())

    if request.method == 'POST':
        message = Message.objects.create(
            user=request.user,
            room=room,
            body=request.POST.get('body')
        )
        room.participants.add(request.user)
        return redirect('room', pk=room.id)

    context = {'room':room, 'room_messages':room_messages,
        'participants':participants}
    return render(request, 'base/room.html', context)
```

Now I want to delete a user from participants when that user deletes all his messages from the room. I am not getting an idea how to proceed here.

In **views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def deleteMessage(request, pk):
    message = Message.objects.get(id=pk)

    room = Room.objects.get(id=pk)
    room_messages = Message.objects.filter(room=room)

    if request.user != message.user:
        return HttpResponse('You are not allowed here!')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        message.delete()
        return redirect('home')

    return render(request, 'base/delete.html', {'obj':message})
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`participants = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='participants', blank=True)`

The `related_name` here should be `rooms`, and not `participants`. This is a pretty common mistake. Although in this case it doesn't affect you.

---

Now for your problem, you have the `Room` instance and the `User` instance, so you can query the `Message` table and if there are no messages with that `User` and `Room` instance combo you can safely remove the user from the room.

```
messages = Message.objects.filter(room=room, user=request.user).count()
if not messages:
    room.participants.remove(request.user)
```